# How to define a macro to conditionally 'comment' specific code?

Tags: c++, arduino-esp32

I have a code with dozens of lines whose I wanted to compile with and without specific lines, as illustrated bellow:

```
x=1;
y=2;  // I want to comment all 'y' assignments on the code
z=3;
```

And I considered to have a macro to conditionally add a comment double-slash before the line in question, this way:

```
x=1;
COMMENT ( y=2; )
z=3;
```

This is the macro definition:

```
#define COMMENTR(x) { //##x }
```

However, the problem is that, during compilation all the content right after double slashes **//** are considered as comments, including the '**}**' C++ statement. As you can see, even the syntaxhighlighter format it as comment.

Is there any other approach to solve the issue ?

Comment: Just do `#define COMMENTR(x)`, with nothing else on that line.  Why create code comments that only the compiler will see?

Comment: You could define a constant say NOCOMPILE and conditionally check as normal, e.g. #if defined(NOCOMPILE)

Answer (score 3):

Comments are handled *before* the preprocessor is run. You can not macro substitute in a comment.

Even if you had this:

```cpp
#define COMMENTR(x) { /* ##x */ }
```

The preprocessor will treat it exactly the same as:

```cpp
#define COMMENTR(x) {   }
```

Just have the macro discard its argument entirely:

```cpp
#if (you want it to be a comment)
#define COMMENTR(...)
#else
#define COMMENTR(...) __VA_ARGS__
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is probably the good old:

```
#ifndef SOME_CONSTANT_HERE
   y=2;
#endif
```

It's a bit more wordy, but on the plus side it handles multiple lines and it doesn't interact badly with comments, semicolons, close-braces, and the rest.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other approach to solve the issue ?

Yes. This feature is called "conditional compilation", [here's a link to the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional).

Here's one way to do what you're trying to do.

Your .cpp file could surround every code you want to conditionally include with conditional preprocessing blocks like this:

```
x=1;
#ifndef REMOVE_Y_ASSIGNMENTS
y=2;
#endif REMOVE_Y_ASSIGNMENTS
z=3;
```

Then at the top of your file, you can add this line to tell the compiler to exclude any code within those preprocessor conditional blocks.

```
#define REMOVE_Y_ASSIGNMENTS
```

This is a pretty useful language feature in moderation, but I feel obligated to warn you that [it can hurt you if used too much in large programs](https://www.cqse.eu/en/news/blog/living-in-the-ifdef-hell/).

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt doesn't work because the comments are removed before the macros are processed.

But you don't need to generate a comment when you can just not generate the code:

```
#define COMMENTR(...)
```

I've replaced `(x)` with `(...)` to be able to handle commas in the argument.

And if you wanted to leave the code unchanged, you'd do `#define COMMENTR(...) __VA_ARGS__`.

Note that such macros have a big disadvantage - if called with a multiline argument, they collapse it to a single line, meaning you can't set line breakpoints inside of one, nor step over them line by line.

For this reason, `#ifdef` should be preferred (or `#ifndef`, `#if`).

The only real reason to use a macro is when you want to disable a part of another macro's argument, because `#ifdef` can't be used there.